# In English, do people say "the Jack" or "the Donald" to specify someone special?

Tags: definite-articles

I heard Donald Trump had the nickname *the Donald*. So I'm curious, can I say

> Did you see the John?

or

> Did you see the Michael?

Do people say it? What if there are five Michaels at a workplace? Would it be normal to use "the *name*"?

Comment: Short answer: No.  "The Donald" is peculiar to Donald Trump.  (and I still think it sounds so odd that I can't bring myself to even say it.)

Comment: The Donald is, was and always will be [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck). Mr Trump's megalomania notwithstanding.

Comment: I beg to differ.  We have a long-haired golden hamster named Donald and we refer to him as "The Donald."

Comment: I will add that *the* is often used with a person's full name to distinguish "the famous one" from others that happen to have the same name.  "The George Bush" is a president;  George Bush is my neighbor. (And when used this way, it's usually pronounced:  *thee*)

Comment: Your last question in particular leaves me puzzled. Even if you could say "the Michael" to refer to the one Michael at your workplace, certainly you wouldn't say that if there are actually five of them? That's like the First Rule of The.

Comment: There is also "the Jack of spades/hearts/clubs and diamonds" :)

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin Does he have a comb-over?

Comment: Note that there are some instances of shortening a person's last name and referring to the person as "the [shortened last name." Thus the TV character Arthur Fonzarelli of the show _Happy Days_ was known as "The Fonz," and in real life the presidential advisor Anthony Scaramucci is frequently referred to as "the Mooch." These designations, like "the Donald" for Donald Trump, convey a mixed message—at once familiar, aggrandizing, humorous/affectionate, and patronizing/sarcastic. I don't know how the Donald and the Mooch feel about their nicknames, but I would hate to be "the Sven."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story I always heard for the origin of "The Donald" is that his ex-wife, Ivana Trump, was a non-native English speaker and was said to have referred to him as such.

Backed up by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Donald_Trump&oldid=593290180#Personal_life):

> Trump is popularly known as **The Donald**, a nickname perpetuated by the media after his first wife Ivana Trump, a native of the Czech Republic, referred to him as such in an interview.[167]

So really, the nickname is somewhat mocking, based on the tendency of Slavic-speaking peoples to have trouble with the correct use of articles.  This is not a natural phrasing or generally applicable in English.

Comment: This is why you don't use Wikipedia as a source. The citation you refer to is no longer in its entry on Mr Trump.

Comment: @Clare - If you'd like I can try digging through history there and linking to the revision at the time I posted.  Edit: It seems wikipedia's ui for this got a lot nicer than last I did it.  About to update the link to this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Donald_Trump&oldid=593290180#Personal_life

Comment: Well that's not the only reason not to cite Wikipedia. The chief reason is that it's not authoritative and not scholarly. The phrase "backed up [supported] by wikipedia" is like saying "backed up by Mr Magoo".

Comment: @Clare Sure. I am sure a lot of "polished" sources end up resembling Mr. Magoo in the end as well. But I addressed a substantive complaint about the post. (And the Wikipedia quote has its own citation of the New York Observer.) I cited Wikipedia when posting this a couple of years ago as a quick sanity check on things I had heard through word of mouth quite some time earlier.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you say that you will only confuse folks.  Donald Trump is the only human, not hamster, I have ever heard referred to in that style.  In Scotland, however, it is fairly common to refer to "The MacDonald" in order to refer to the patriarch of the clan MacDonald or whatever clan you are discussing.  There is the slightly humorous expression, "The Mackintosh of Mackintosh in his Mackintosh".

Comment: I have two comments to make. 1.'Mackintosh' when used to describe a full-length waterproof coat, is normally spelled with a small m, notwithstanding its being named after Charles Mackintosh (1766-1843) the Scottish inventor. 2. According to my dictionary it is a British term. I note you live in Boston MA, and am wondering if you call them mackintoshes in the eastern United States?

Comment: The upper-case "M" is because I was just reading a thread deploring the modern habit of dropping capitalizations when a name has become a common term, product, or unit such as "abelian group", "mackintosh", or "hertz".  I went with the spelling from the product website, which seems to be the common one for the coat if not the clan.  I'm from Ohio, of Scots-Irish ancestry, and I would call them rain coats, whether they were rubberized or not.  :-)

Comment: The abbreviation 'mac'may still survive a little among us oldies, but it has been a long time since I heard anyone say 'mackintosh'. That made me even more surprised to hear it used. Besides they have given way to waterproof hoodie things these days, which used to be called 'anoraks', but youngsters avoid that word like the plague nowadays.

Comment: I see the macintosh survives at this website. But I cannot imagine who pays those prices for one! http://www.mrporter.com/Shop/Designers/Mackintosh?cm_mmc=GoogleLDNc-_-Designer_-_Mackintosh-_-Mackintosh_-_Exact-_-mackintosh-mt:e-sn:g&gclid=CJyc0K7hmrwCFdQPtAodkg8AEw

Answer (score 2):

It's rare, but not unheard of. [Sir Donald Bradman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Bradman) is sometimes referred to as "The Don".